# React web app not receiving Firebase notifications

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `firebase@8.2.0` to implement foreground notifications in the React web app and I do not receive any messages/notifications sent from the firebase console.

After sending a message in the firebase console like this:

[image]

In a tutorial I'm following, they produce this result:

[image]

However no messages are received and logged to the console when I do the testing:

[image]

Below is my code for firebase messaging:

**src/firebase.ts**

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";
import { firebaseConfig } from './constants';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  firebase.app();
}

let messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    messaging = firebase.messaging();
  }
}

export const getMessagingToken = async () => {
  let currentToken = "";
  if (!messaging) return;
  try {
    currentToken = await messaging.getToken({
      vapidKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_FCM_VAPID_KEY, // already hard-coded in test code
    });
    console.log("FCM registration token", currentToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", error);
  }
  return currentToken;
};

export const onMessageListener = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      resolve(payload);
    });
  });
```

**App.tsx**

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getMessagingToken, onMessageListener } from './firebase';
import logo from './logo.svg';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getMessagingToken();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    onMessageListener().then((data) => {
      console.log('Receive foreground: ', data);
    });
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have checked:

- `firebaseConfig`
- `vapidKey`
- allowed notifications in both Chrome and Firefox
- setup my web app in `Project settings > Web apps` in Firebase Console

This is the tutorial I'm taking reference from, sorry if it's not in english but I'll leave it here just in case https://viblo.asia/p/reactjs-push-notification-su-dung-firebase-cloud-messaging-yZjJYE9XJOE

Comment: Have you created, even if empty, the file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` ?  This is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground